# What is necessary to create more advanced, dynamic and user friendly web pages?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML and CSS for creating web pages.  I want my web pages to be more dynamic and user friendly, so which languages do I need to learn to do so?

Comment: Based on the chosen question title, try Cobol or Fortran. (Sorry, that was really mean. I just couldn’t help it.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly you want to do, but you can do a lot with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) which "just" uses [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and XML data files. As this still runs on the client side you don't need any changes to your web server. The content is still static.

To go further and generate content as requested you'll need to get into server side languages like [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asp.net) etc. for which you might need a new hosting environment. These generate the page server site and the user views that. These still use JavaScript on the client side to perform the "user friendliness" though.